# Handle unique values in tabular input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hope you all doing fine.

**Scenario**

I have a junction model **resumeSkills** that takes the id of resume and the id of skill from different tables and another field "proficiency level" to determine the expertise in that particular skill.

[image: Unique Key Violation for skill]
I have multiple instances of this model loaded in my page based on "Add New" button click (which triggers a Jquery AJAX callback which interns, creates a model against given index counter).
Every model instance is validated based on model rules defined so it works fine if I have different values selected for every instance created.

**Target**
Now, I want to add skills in a way that If I select "php" in any model-instance in my view either I am not able to select "php" in any of newly generated model-instances or I don't see in there respective drop-down/tags.

**Problem**

Now if I select the same value for multiple instances (above figure), Validation fails against second or later record as I have rule that skills can not be duplicated against a resume.

This is where I need Help from the community.

**Here is my controller action method to add new model instance (record) in the view (append the content container)**

```
public function actionAddNewRecord($idresume, $index)
{
    $model = new OresumeResumeSkill();
    $model->idresume = $idresume;
    $model->isDeleted = 0;
    $model->isFromDb = 0;

    $response = [];

    $response['content'] = $this->renderPartial('_partials/_add_new_form', [
        'model' => $model, 'i'=>$index
    ]);

    return Json::encode($response);
}
```

Here is the code to my main partial file:
**_edit_file.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- container that has form and its operations in it -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">

<?php

    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'form_edit_resume_skill_multiple',
        'options' => [
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'class' => 'section_form',
        ],
    ]);

?>
    <div id="add_new_record_container">
    <!--
        Add new Item related item_container will be placed in here dynamically in parallel
        This loaded content is based on _add_new_form partial view
        Content is added via AJAX request caused by btn_add_new_record
    -->
    </div>

    <div class="row form_controls">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnCounter" id="hdnCounter" value="<?php echo count($skills); ?>" />
            <?php echo Html::a(T::t('main', 'Add New'), ['/oresume/resume-skill/add-new-record', 'idresume'=>$model_resume->idresume], ['id'=>'btn_add_new_record', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary' ]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <?php echo Html::a(T::t('main', 'Cancel'), ['/oresume/attachment/discard-all-drafts'], ['class'=>'btn btn-default', 'id'=>'btnDiscardChanges', 'data'=>['confirm_message'=>T::t('main', 'Discard Changes?'), ] ]);?>
            <?php echo Html::submitButton(T::t('main', 'Save Changes'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($form->attributes);?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            <?php 
                $options = Json::htmlEncode($form->options);
                $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($form->attributes);          
            ?>

            $("#<?php echo $form->options['id'];?>").yiiActiveForm(<?php echo $attributes;?>, <?php echo $options;?>);

            $(".resume_skills").select2({
                tags: true,
                multiple: true,
                maximumSelectionLength: 1,
                language: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->language; ?>",
                allowClear: true,
                placeholder: {
                    idskill: "",
                    placeholder: "<?php echo T::t('main', 'Please select'); ?>"
                },
            });

            var attributes = <?php echo $attributes;?>; 
            for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
                $("#form_edit_resume_skill_multiple").yiiActiveForm('add', attributes[i]);
            }
        });
    </script>


<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- //container that has form and its operations in it -->
</div>
```

Here is the code for my sub_partial file (to add a new model instance):
**_add_new_form.php**

```
$title = T::t('main', 'Add New Record');

$skills = OresumeSkill::listSkills();
$proficiencyLevels = OresumeResumeSkill::listProficiencyLevels();

$form = ActiveForm::begin();
?>

<div class="col-xs-12 item_container">

    <div class="row single_value_row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]idskill")->dropDownList($skills, ['style'=>['width'=>'100%'], 'class'=>'resume_skills', 'placeholder'=>T::t('main', 'Please select')]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]level")->dropDownList($proficiencyLevels, ['prompt' => T::t('main', 'Please Select')]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-left">
            <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn_remove_record" id="btnRemoveResumeSkill-<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo T::t('main', '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'); ?></button>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]isDeleted")->hiddenInput(['class'=>'isDeleted_input'])->label(false); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, "[$i]isFromDb")->hiddenInput(['class'=>'isFromDb_input'])->label(false); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#form_edit_resume_skill_multiple").yiiActiveForm('add', 'OresumeResumeSkill[<?php echo $i; ?>]');

            $(".resume_skills").select2({
                tags: true,
                multiple: true,
                maximumSelectionLength: 1,
                language: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->language; ?>",
                allowClear: true,
                placeholder: {
                    idskill: "",
                    placeholder: "<?php echo T::t('main', 'Please select'); ?>"
                },
            });

            <?php $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($form->attributes);?>
            var attributes = <?php echo $attributes; ?>;
            for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
                $("#form_edit_resume_skill_multiple").yiiActiveForm('add', attributes[i]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>


<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And here is the code for my action that handles the dynamically generated models and save them in db.

```
Public function actionGetResumeSkills($idresume)
    {
        $model_resume = OresumeResume::findOne($idresume);
        $models = OresumeResumeSkill::getResumeSkills($model_resume->idresume);

        $response = [];

        $postedArray = \Yii::$app->request->post('OresumeResumeSkill');
        //         print_r($postedArray);

        if( count($postedArray) )  //case: Its a postback and we have some models in it
        {
            if(count($models) < count($postedArray) )//case: postback has more number of models as compared to in db
            {
                //  Generate empty models array to be filled by loadMultiple() method of model class
                //  create emoty models and add in models array counter so that
                //  we've equal number of sent / recieved models for processing
                for ($i=count($models); $i< count($postedArray); $i++ )
                {
                    $model = new OresumeResumeSkill();
                    $model->idresume = $idresume;
                    $models[] = $model;
                }
            }
        }

        if( count($models) == 0) //  we need to check if this array has something to process
        {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['message'] = T::t('main', 'No records found to process');
        }

        if(OresumeResumeSkill::loadMultiple($models, \Yii::$app->request->post())) //  load multiple models of models array
        {
            $status = true;

            foreach ($models as $model)
            {
                //  Delete models that are flaged to do so
                //  execute continue statement on deletion

                //  Validate and save models that are to be saved/updated
                $model->idskill = OresumeResumeSkill::getSkill($model->idskill);
                $model->level = ($model->level != null)? $model->level : OresumeResumeSkill::LEVEL_BEGINNER;
                if( $model->validate() )    //  Case: Model data is valid
                {
                    //  Save Model in database
                    $status &= $model->save();
                }
                else
                {
                    $status = false;
                    //                     print_r($model->errors['idskill'][0]);
                    $response['message'] = T::t("main", "Storing of record \"{$model->idskill0->name}\" got some validation issues\n");
                }
            }

            if($status)
            {
                $model_resume = OresumeResume::findOne($model->idresume);
                $models = OresumeResumeSkill::getResumeSkills($model->idresume);

                $response['status'] = true;
                $response['content'] = $this->renderPartial('_partials/_edit_form', ['model_resume' => $model_resume, 'skills' => $models]);
                $response['counter'] = count($models);
                $response['message'] = T::t('main', 'Record(s) updated Successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                $response['status'] = false;
                //  $response['message'] = T::t('main', 'Records could not be updated.\n Something went wrong');
            }
        }
        else // case: page loads for the first time
        {
            $response['content'] = $this->renderPartial('_partials/_edit_form', ['model_resume'=>$model_resume, 'skills' => $models]);
        }

        return Json::encode($response);
    }
```

Any Help is Appreciated.
thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this on a phone so there are a few parts of your code I'm not sure I totally get and I won't be able to type much. However, from my understanding, you don't want already selected skills to show up in next drop down.

You can have a hidden field to keep the IDs of selected skills (comma separated) and pass that as an argument to the listSkills method. Means your listSkills method will change a bit to accept a parameter.

In your listSkills method you have to use a where clause that says where skill ID NOT IN the list of IDs coming from the hidden field. Means you will be selecting back only the skills that have not been selected before into your array for the drop down.

Sorry I'm on a phone, I can't add code samples.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
but I tried this and still need help with your idea.
Could you manage to write some code please?